# How to make the content appear in an object element?

Tags: php, html

am using Firefox 20.0.1

```
<object type="text/html" data="nature.php" style=" margin:1%;overflow:hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%"></object>
```

The content page (nature.php) appears clipped on screen.

Answer (score 0):

The `object` element is not for including complete pages into another. It is for including Java Applets or Flash Programs.

Comment: for including pages,write them in php instead of htlm, and uyse the php commande include